# custom filter won't update live results on iPhone

Tags: ios, angularjs, angularjs-filter

**UPDATE:** [Here's a plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/JKLhlgzkOmk9drfBrUiH?p=preview)

I have a basic search field that displays matching names from a JSON array of employee data:

```
<form>
    <label>Enter name: <input type="text" ng-model="search"></label>
</form>

<ul class="result-container" ng-if="search.length>1">
    <li class="result" ng-repeat="emp in employees | filter:{full_name:search}">
</ul>
```

This works fine, but because it's mobile, I wanted to reduce the size of the JSON download as much as possible. Since the `full_name` field is created on-the-fly as a concatenation of `first_name` and `last_name`, I could strip that field out of the JSON completely if I could search both first and last name instead.

So I created a custom filter:

```
app.filter('firstAndLastName', function() {
    return function(collection, str) {
        return collection.filter(function(el) { // javascript array.filter()
            return (el.first_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(str) !== -1 || el.last_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(str) !== -1);
        });
    };
});
```

and updated my view to use it:

```
    <li class="result" ng-repeat="emp in employees |  firstAndLastName:search">
```

This works as expected on my desktop browsers -- results are live-updated as text is typed. But on mobile, it no longer displays any results at all, whether the keyboard is open or not. This happens in both Safari and Chrome (iOS 8.0.2).

I tried [making my filter stateful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25877704/what-is-a-stateful-filtering-in-angularjs), but that didn't change anything. (I'm currently using AngularJS 1.3.0-rc.4.)

Why does the AngularJS built-in filter update live results, but my custom filter does not? And why does this only happen on mobile?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you've tried it out but anyway have you tried clearing the cache of your mobile browser?

Comment: Incidentally, the ultimate goal of this was to allow me to remove the "full name" field from my JSON, reducing it's size by 20-25% percent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to make sure both the input and search string are set to lowercase:

```
app.filter('firstAndLastName', function() {
    return function(collection, str) {
        var strToLower = str.toLowerCase();
        return collection.filter(function(el) { // javascript array.filter()
            return (el.first_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(strToLower) !== -1 || el.last_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(strToLower) !== -1);
        });
    };
});
```

I realized that my phone was auto-capitalizing the first letter and was causing the results not to show. If that is not it you might need to put some more information as to how the data is getting in there.