# AngularJS v1.3 breaks translations filter

Tags: angularjs

In Angular v1.2 I was using the following code for serving up localised strings in the application:

```
var i18n = angular.module('i18n', []);

i18n.service('i18n', function ($http, $timeout) {
    /**
        A dictionary of translations keyed on culture
    */
    this.translations = {},

    /**
        The current culture
    */
    this.currentCulture = null,

    /**
        Sets the current culture, loading the associated translations file if not already loaded
    */
    this.setCurrentCulture = function (culture) {
        var self = this;
        if (self.translations[culture]) {
            $timeout(function () {
                self.currentCulture = culture;
            });
        } else {
            $http({ method: 'GET', url: 'i18n/' + culture + '/translations.json?' + Date.now() })
                .success(function (data) {
                    // $timeout is used here to defer the $scope update to the next $digest cycle
                    $timeout(function () {
                        self.translations[culture] = data;
                        self.currentCulture = culture;
                    });
                }); 
        }
    };

    this.getTranslation = function (key) {
        if (this.currentCulture) {
            return this.translations[this.currentCulture][key] || key;
        } else {
            return key;
        }
    },

    // Initialize the default culture
    this.setCurrentCulture(config.defaultCulture);
});

i18n.filter('i18n', function (i18n) {
    return function (key) {
        return i18n.getTranslation(key);
    };
});
```

In the template it is then used as follows:

```
<p>{{ 'HelloWorld' | i18n }}</p>
```

For some reason that I can't fathom, upgrading to v1.3 of AngularJS has broken this functionality.  Either the $timeout isn't triggering a digest cycle, or the filter isn't updating.  I can see that the $timeout code is running, but the filter code never gets hit.

Any ideas why this might be broken in v1.3?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In angular 1.3 the filtering was changed so that they are no longer "stateful". You can see more info in this question: [What is stateful filtering in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25877704/what-is-a-stateful-filtering-in-angularjs)

The end result is that filter will no longer re-evaluate unless the input changes. To fix this you can add the line:

```
i18n.filter('i18n', function (i18n) {
    var filter = function (key) {
        return i18n.getTranslation(key);
    };
    filter.$stateful = true;    ///add this line
    return filter;
});
```

Or else implement your filter some other way.