# what is mean stateless filter in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I don't understand the concept of state and stateless filter in angular js. Could please explain it more. In angular js documentation mentioned "Many stateful filters can be converted into stateless filters just by exposing the hidden state"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is stateful filtering in AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25877704/what-is-stateful-filtering-in-angularjs)

Comment: stateless filter not explained there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25877704/what-is-stateful-filtering-in-angularjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all "state" means variables/properties of the entire application scope. And a statefull filter will have access to all these variable which is not necessary to perform desired action of the filter and stateless filter will not have access to any of the application variable instead the data necessary for that filter will be passed to it.